# Could someone help me about the proof of this propositions about weighted median?

Tags: statistics

**Proposition:** Let $ x_1 x_2, \ldots, x_n$ be an ordered sample ($x_i < x_{i+1}$) and $\omega_1,\ldots, \omega_n$ a set of weighs, $\omega_i>0$. Consider the strictly increseasing succession defined as,

$\varphi_{0} = - \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i$

$\varphi_{r+1} = \varphi_{r} + 2\omega_{r+1}\;\;$,  $r=1,\ldots, n-1$

Then ,the minimum of the function $\Delta (\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i |x_i-\beta|$, is attached at $\hat{\beta}$, where

1. $\hat{\beta} = x_{s}$, if $\varphi_s$ is the first positive value and $\varphi_r \neq 0$, $\forall \; r$
2. $\hat{\beta}$ is any value of the interval $[x_{s},x_{s+1}]$ if $\varphi_s = 0 $

*Remark: $\hat{\beta}$ is known as weighted median.*